# How to retrieve the exit-code from a transient systemd unit using the gdbus utility

Tags: shell-script, systemd, d-bus

From within a **Docker container** I'm able to create a **transient systemd unit** in the **host Linux OS** to run a script.  The script returns exit 0 on success, exit 1 on failure.  The script below creates the transient unit:

```
job_name=$(transient-unit-`date +%s%N`.service)
cmd="~/my_script_that_runs_on_the_host.sh"

gdbus call \
    --system \
    --dest=org.freedesktop.systemd1 \
    --object-path /org/freedesktop/systemd1 \
    --method org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager.StartTransientUnit \
    ${job_name} fail "[('ExecStart', <[('/bin/sh', ['/bin/sh','-c', ${cmd}], false)]>)]" "[]" || true
```

I'm trying to sort out the proper gdbus syntax to get the exit status of the script from the transient unit so corrective action can be taken in case of failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exit status of the "main" process in ExecStart= is available as the `ExecMainStatus` property on the `org.freedesktop.systemd1.Service` interface on the object representing the loaded unit, as long as that unit hasn't been garbage-collected and unloaded.

The first step is to call `Manager.GetUnit(name)` to retrieve the object path for that unit:

```
# gdbus call -y -d org.freedesktop.systemd1 \
                -o /org/freedesktop/systemd1 \
                -m org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager.GetUnit \
                   "foo.service"
(objectpath '/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/foo_2eservice',)
```

Properties are accessed by calling methods on the `org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties` interface:

```
# gdbus call -y -d org.freedesktop.systemd1 \
                -o /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/foo_2eservice \
                -m org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get \
                   "org.freedesktop.systemd1.Service" \
                   "ExecMainStatus"
(<2>,)
```

(You will also see the properties in `gdbus introspect` and `busctl introspect.)

If you have systemd, you also have busctl, which has a `busctl get-property` wrapper and a syntax more suitable for use in shell scripts (i.e. you need to specify the signature upfront but you can pass each dict value as an individual argument – avoids the quoting-related problems you would have with gdbus):

```
# busctl call org.freedesktop.systemd1 \
              /org/freedesktop/systemd1 \
              org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager \
              GetUnit s "foo.service"
o "/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/foo_2eservice"

# busctl call org.freedesktop.systemd1 \
              /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/foo_2eservice \
              org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties \
              Get ss "org.freedesktop.systemd1.Service" "ExecMainStatus"
v i 2

# busctl get-property org.freedesktop.systemd1 \
                      /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/foo_2eservice \
                      org.freedesktop.systemd1.Service \
                      ExecMainStatus
i 2
```

Comment: Thank you!  Based on your comment, to get this fully working I need to pass "RemainAfterExit=yes" when creating the transient system unit so I can read the exit status.  I'm totally striking out at getting that syntax correct.

Comment: The overall syntax, if you're using `gdbus`, is that you're passing an array of comma-separated `('string', <variant>)` pairs (e.g. `('Foo', <'string value'>)` or `('Foo', <true>)`). I don't think you need RemainAfterExit, though – that does something a bit different and affects the unit's actual "start/stop" status. For this purpose you want to set CollectMode instead.